# Which Clustering algorithm to use for unique 4Dimension dataset before feeding to correlation?

Tags: python, clustering, dbscan

Lets give an example
`X: 1 2 3 4 5
Y: .9 .91 .92 .93 .94
Z: 20 36 999 211
M. 4000 3456 1 0`

When I have such dataset, Which clustering algorithm to choose ? Also, How to interpret the results after clustering ?
Meaning: How to feed 4D dataset into cluster.

I found DBSCAN available on internet for 2D with which plot is possible. Since my dataset is 4 D and varies ILLOGICALLY...I am afraid to feed this to Algorithm

`

```
import pdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import square, sqrt
def regionQuery(P, eps, D): 
    neighbourPts = []
    for point in D:
        #print point        
        if sqrt(square(P[1] - point[1]) + square(P[2] - point[2]))<eps:
            neighbourPts.append(point)
    return neighbourPts
def DBSCAN(D, eps, MinPts):
    noise = []
    visited = []
    C = []
    c_n = -1
    for point in D:
        visited.append(point) #marking point as visited
    #   print point     
        neighbourPts = regionQuery(point, eps, D)
        if len(neighbourPts) < MinPts:
            noise.append(point)
        else:
            C.append([])            
            c_n+=1
            expandCluster(point, neighbourPts, C, c_n,eps, MinPts, D, visited)
    print("no. of clusters: " , len(C)  )
    print("length of noise:", len(noise))
    for cluster in C:
        col =[rand(1),rand(1),rand(1)]      
        #print(cluster)     
        plt.scatter([i[1] for i in cluster],[i[2] for i in cluster],color=col)
    plt.show()
def expandCluster(P, neighbourPts, C, c_n,eps, MinPts, D, visited):
    C[c_n].append(P)
    for point in neighbourPts:
        if point not in visited:
            visited.append(point) 
            neighbourPts_2 = regionQuery(point, eps, D)
            if len(neighbourPts_2) >= MinPts:
                neighbourPts += neighbourPts_2
        if point not in (i for i in C):
            C[c_n].append(point)
eps =20#input("enter eps")
x=200*rand(10)
y=200*rand(10)
l=[]
for i in range(10):
    l.append([i,x[i],y[i]])
#pdb.set_trace()
DBSCAN(l,eps,1)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN is not limited to 2d (apparently you only found very bad implementations) and can be used with correlation distance, too.

But mostly, you need to focus on preprocessing.

If you intend to do correlation anyway, you should consider to z normalize your input data, I.e. `x'= (x - mean(x))/stddev(x)`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan is n-dimensional.
you can try also WEKA, SPMF library